# RN52 Custom Circuit Board Generating a Loud Buzz While Playing Audio

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, audio, bluetooth, digital-audio

I'm in the process of creating a custom circuit board using an RN52 with a PIC16 controller to hack into my car's stereo and pretend to be a CD changer. The device does work, but while the audio plays there is a loud buzz/whine that makes it unlistenable. This is the first circuit board I've designed, so before I go and trial and error modifications, I figured I'd post it here and see if there's anything obvious I'm missing. Here are the schematics/board configuration.

[image: Schematics]

[image: Layout]

Comment: look at the schematic diagram in the RN52 evaluation kit user guide

Comment: I don't know what the connections to the 13-pin CD changer connector should be, but why have you shorted speaker L- and R- together? Also why is the analog ground disconnected?

Comment: Unwanted noise often indicates a lack of proper power supply filtering and bypass. There should be capacitors in the input and output of the voltage regulators, as well as the power pins of the PIC. Please provide a link to a datasheet for the RN52.

Comment: The datasheet has an example schematic you can more or less copy, start with that.  And don't put the antenna on top of a ground plane, position it like the pictures in the datasheet show hanging off the board.

Comment: The CD changer only has one negative connector so I figured combining them both would be fine. After looking at the the evaluation kit user guide, I did notice the analog ground. Does it matter if I connect it to the main ground? It seems like that's what the user guide shows. For some reason I didn't consider including capacitors for the 7805, but I'll add that to my next revision.

Comment: @aNigerianPrince Please ask a specific question

Comment: @VoltageSpike you genuinely trying to help solve my problem? Or did you just feel like reviving a post from nearly a year ago to point out the annoyance of inexperienced people asking questions and therefore increasing the visibility of a “low quality” post?

Comment: It came up for closure, I was trying to make the question better. I don't have time to moderate and answer questions most of the time